# internetexplorer.application object - getting item by class

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, vba

I am using VBA to open a web page and need to collect the value of some elements that have a specific class.

```
With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.google.com"
    While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set r = .document.getelementsbyclassname("gssb_f")
    ' REST OF CODE
End With
```

The above does not work.

I am also struggling to find a library of all available properties and methods for the `InternetExplorer.Application` object. Does it exist?

Comment: The above code looks ok to me. What exact error does it give you? You might also want to try `.Document.Body.getElementsByClassName("gssb_f")`

Comment: I don't think getElementsbyClassName is supported in IE

Comment: getElementsByClassName does not work... I am using VBA (Excel) and get an error "Object does not support this property or method" ! A way around is to loop through all elements and check the ".className" property against the one I want.

Comment: IF you can upgrade to ie9 your code will work, as you've discovered getelementsbyclassname isn't included in earlier versions

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `.querySelectorAll` method of `document` to apply a CSS selector of

```
.gssb_f
```

The "." means className. This method returns a `nodeList` which you can loop over by traversing the `.Length` of the returned `nodeList`.

Syntax:

```
.document.querySelectorAll(".gssb_f")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA Editor, you should try to add references to 'Microsoft Internet Controls'.
Click on 'Tools' > 'References' > Check 'Microsoft Internet Controls' > Click OK.

My guess is this should work.

-Nin

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for a workaround for this and could only find this. I'm posting an example  of the idea @davidbeyonchen had in case anyone else has this issue. I was only searching for one item, but it could be modified to include multiple items.

```
For Each elem In .Document.all
    If elem.className = "gssb_f" Then
        Set r = elem
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```